# Passing objects to wcf webservice in iphone

Tags: iphone

what should be the request for a wcf webservice method which excepts an object as a parameter?i have a method which accepts an object of class employee. The request below gives an error:Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
int id1=100;

NSString *soapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                     "<soap:Body>"
                     "<TestEmployee xmlns=\"http://body.com/\">"
                     "<Employee>"
                     "<id>%d</id>"
                     "<Name>%@</Name>"
                     "</Employee>"
                     "</TestEmployee>"
                     "</soap:Body>"
                     "</soap:Envelope>",id1,@"abc"];
```

Answer (score 1):

For the webservices I always prefer to use the tool available[here](http://sudzc.com/). In this is the link you can provide your webservice and it will create the classes and examples for you to test.
I hope this would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

SudzC (The link UPT referenced) works great for WCF services. You can point the tool to either a web accessible WSDL or a local one. It may be beneficial to start by pointing SudzC at the national weather service WSDL http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl in order to test a known SOAP service and familiarize yourself with SudzC.

Another useful link for determining Soap message structure is
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit

That should at least get you in the right direction.